# Can one define a covariant derivative on a generic differential algebra?

Tags: differential-geometry, commutative-algebra, differential-topology, lie-algebras, connections

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a commutative algebra and let $Der(\mathcal{A})$ be its associated algebra of derivations (  $Der(\mathcal{A})$ is assumed to be non-empty).

A covariant derivative is a map $$\nabla: Der(\mathcal{A}) \times Der(\mathcal{A}) \to Der(\mathcal{A})$$

denoted by $$\nabla_XY$$ that satisfies the properties:

a. It is tensorial ($\mathcal{A}$-linear) in the first (index argument)

b. It is $\mathbb{R}$-linear in the second argument

c. It satisfies the product rule in the second argument:  $$ \nabla_X(fY)=X(f)Y+f(\nabla_XY)$$ for all $X,Y \in Der(\mathcal{A})$ and for all $f \in  \mathcal{A}$

If $Der(\mathcal{A})$ is a free module one can always construct a covariant derivative on $Der(\mathcal{A}).$ If $Der(\mathcal{A})$ is the Lie Algebra of smooth vector fields on a a smooth manifold one can always define $\nabla$ using a partition of unity. Could this be done for a generic $Der(\mathcal{A})?$